# Why is there no Remote Machine option underneath the start menu in my Visual Studio 2019 Community version

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, hololens

I had the free trial for the Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise version. Now that it has run out, I am trying to run my build from Unity using that .sln file in visual studio using the community version. I need to use the remote machine option because I am trying to deploy it to the HoloLens. I already tried rebuilding the unity project but I still had the same problem. Is it because when I created this Unity project I was using the enterprise version and now it can't translate the same way over to the community version? Does the community version not have the remote machine capability? I've attached a picture below of what I mean by "the start menu." Back in the enterprise version I would press that little down arrow to expand the Start menu and I would press "Remote Machine," but that option is no longer there when I try to run a .sln build from my Unity project.
[image: start menu]

Comment: Did you turn on developer mode on both the Visual Studio computer and the HoloLens? It is a prerequisite for deploying an app over Wi-Fi. Besides, USB cable can be an alternative to deploy and debug, more information please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-visual-studio

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT thank you for the response, both are in developer mode and I can't deploy over USB either because I cannot select the deploy to "Device" option under the start menu because the only option under the start menu is start.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you have selected the correct project for the startup project? If you have a mistake in setting the startup project, there will only be a **Start** option under the menu. You can change the startup project from the **Solution Explorer**, right-click the desired project and choose **Set as StartUp Project** from the context-sensitive menu that is displayed.

If you still get this issue, can you see the **Remote machine** field under Project settings’ Debug tab: [Configure the project for remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-on-a-remote-machine?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Choosing_the_remote_device_for_C__and_Visual_Basic_projects)

If yes, you just need to enter the network name or IP address in the Remote machine field, or select Find to search for the device in the Remote Connections dialog box.

If not, I believe you need to repair the VS installation.

Comment: Thank you for the help but it is still not working. I made sure it was selected as the startup project. For some reason, there is no debugging tab. When I go to properties under project settings, and then under Configuration Properties there is only a general tab, no debugging tab. Back when I first made this project using enterprise, I remember there being a debugging tab there, but in my VS community version there is not.

Comment: @philipdority Could you reconfirm that your project type is *Universal Windows*? This keyword means this project is a UWP application. And you can check it by whether the bracketed content of the item listed in a bold typeface in the Solution Explorer is *Universal Windows*. Besides, in your unity project, Script Backend should be IL2CPP. If this item is .NET, there will be multiple Universal Windows  project in your Solution Explorer, but right-click they and choose "Properties" you will find that their output type is Class Library so they should not be a startup project for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I put my machine in "developer mode" via the Settings and then opened my project in VS 2022. I'm now able to see the "Remote Machine" option.

Comment: how exactly did you put you machine into "developer mode"?